# Js mqtt client is not connecting to the publisher

Tags: mqtt

I have created a simple node js broker and publisher and is working fine , have a look at the code below

```
broker
--------------
//MQTT broker
var mosca = require('mosca')
var settings =  {port:3000}
var broker= new mosca.Server(settings)


broker.on('ready',()=>{
    console.log("Broker is ready")
})
```

And the publisher is

```
//mqtt publisher
var mqtt=require('mqtt')
var client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://127.0.0.1:3000")
var topic = "ping"
var message = "Ping button"


client.on("connect",()=>{
    setInterval(()=>{
        client.publish(topic,message)
        console.log("clicked",message)
    },5000)
})
```

And the i created an html file including js to connect to that mqtt broker

```
var mqtt;
    var reconnectTimeOut=2000;
    var host="127.0.0.1";
    var port=3000;

    function onConnect(){
        console.log("Connected");
        message= new Paho.MQTT.Message("I am Connected");
        message.destinationName="ping";
        mqtt.send(message);
    }
    function MQTTconnect(){
        console.log("Connecting to host");
        mqtt=new Paho.MQTT.Client(host,port,"ping");
        var options={
            timeout : 3000,
            onSuccess: onConnect,
        };
        mqtt.connect(options);
    }
    MQTTconnect();
```

And there is no error , But the client doesn't connect to the server, Not executing the onConnect

Answer (score 1):

Your broker is only creating a native MQTT listener on port 3000, when you try to connect using the Paho JavaScript client from the browser it will ONLY be able to connect to the broker using MQTT over WebSockets which the broker is not listening for.

You will need to add WebSocket support to your broker on a separate port, a how to for mosca can be found [here](https://github.com/moscajs/mosca/wiki/MQTT-over-Websockets)